# Richard has too many badges!

Tags: bug, design, badges

[Richard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/richard) has *way* too many badges -- so many, in fact, that they don't all fit on the page!

[image: Image with an answer by Richard, with the number of bronze badges cut off at the end, by the hot network questions from the side of the page]

The linked answer may be found [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/81298/41144).

---

*btw; congatulations on becoming a moderator, Richard!*